# Error "The case-insensitive file shouldn't be copied twice in one bulk copy" in Yarn package manager

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I've just upgrade to Yarn v1.0.2 (stable) and when I do a `yarn install` I'm getting lots of these warnings:

> The case-insensitive file shouldn't be copied twice in one bulk copy

What is this complaining about? How do I fix it?

Comment: see https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4363

Comment: Summarising that link: it's a bug and they're working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest yarn versions are hiding this annoying message. You can use the nightly version (via https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/nightly) until this issue totally fixed (you can track https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3751)